# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi combobox funcione?

Tags: java

Al ejecutar el código no me aparecen los registros solicitados

```
public void Combobox(){
    try{ 
        conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo_seguridad","root","75:)82paco");                     
        st=conexion.createStatement(); 
        rs=st.executeQuery("Select nombre from clientes");
        while (rs.next()){
            this.jcb_clientes.addItem(rs.getString("nombre"));
        }
        }catch(SQLException err){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error "+err.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Te da algún error o lo que te pasa es que no te carga lo obtenido de la consulta?

Comment: Debes formatear el texto para que el código se entienda, edita la pregunta y marca el botón '{ }' para convertirlo en formato código

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Te sale algún tipo de error? Como defines la variable JComboBox? Te faltaría colocar esa parte del código para tener un poco más de precisión en la respuesta

Comment: Te entra al catch? qué error te lanza?